# Jelastic volume mount errors when scaling or creating new environment using JPS

Tags: jelastic

On Jelastic, I was randomly getting the following volume errors when creating a new environment or scaling horizontally.

"Mount to exported directory /xxx/yyyy is forbidden"
"mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting ... RPC connection: 124 "
"mount.nfs: connection timed out ..."

For me, fix was to check all volume configs from JPS, the configuration problem was on a different volume than the error in logs described, so it was a bit misleading. (I had a mismatch on volumes and volumeMounts).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No question, just possible answer because that was a quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

File /etc/exports on shared NFS node should be updated automatically with IPs of connected nodes for all scaling events (ScaleIn/ScaleOut), obviously something went wrong. Could you please provide more details (environment name and hosting service provider name)? 
Thanks in advance!